# Line Break within Circular Progress Bar with react-circular-progressbar?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, styling

I'm currently trying to have a line break within the circular progress bar for my react component. I want the percentage and the "done!" to be both centered and separate Currently, I've tried putting `\n` within the text prop, but that hasn't worked. Is there any idea how I can do this?

The react-circular-progress bar is https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-circular-progressbar.

And Here's My Code:

```
<CircularProgressbar 
        value={props.percentage} 
        text={`${props.percentage}% done!`} 
        counterClockwise
        strokeWidth={4}
        styles={buildStyles({
            // Colors
            pathColor: `#EDD9A8`,
            textColor: 'var(--theme_color)',
            trailColor: 'var(--theme_color',
          })}
         />
```

Comment: Did you add `white-space: pre-wrap;` CSS to your element when you added `\n`?

Comment: @DavidAlsbright how would I do that? I'm not sure where would be appropriate to add the custom CSS, given that text is the default prop of CircularProgressBar.